# How do I stop and uninstall Geth (deleting everything)?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am completely new to Ethereum and Geth. I tried to install Geth, and while it was syncing, I realized mining ethereum on my laptop would not be a good idea, as I don't have a GPU and it would be too slow.

Now I would like to uninstall Geth from my computer. How do I get the syncing to stop? I tried uninstalling the geth app, but it said "`Windows cannot find c:\Program Files\Geth\uninstall.exe`"

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: To add to the above, I am using Windows 10.

Comment: If you feel your question has been answered, could you please mark it so other users know :)

Answer (score 1):

Delete your `data-dir` folder and the `Ethereum` folder. They hold keys and the blockchain you've downloaded respectively (obviously back up the keys if you plan on using them again).

Step 1: Locate and Delete the `Ethereum` folder

The `Ethereum` folder is located at `C:\Users\<your user>\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\`.

From here it's just a matter of removing the Geth binaries that you installed on your computer.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these instructions: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Mac. After installing brew, when you install geth with brew, it will a) put in an accessible location for you, and b) insert the binaries into your $PATH ( which means you can run geth from the Terminal from any folder location. Before starting Mist, open up the terminal, and run the geth --help command. You'll see all the options available. The default cache size is rather small so by setting --cache you're overriding the default ( same with --maxpeers ). Once you've got geth running in the terminal, THEN open up Mist, and wait forever. I would open up Activity Monitor as well, to see how close you are to maxing out your ram ( or, perhaps you can increase it ... --cache=4096 or more??? ). Let Mist sync. Don't Launch the App manually, wait until it catches up ( took me 2 weeks on my platter ). Once it's sync'd up, if you can leave your computer on most of the time, I would close Mist, stop geth, and restart it using a more reasonable cache size ( 1024 ) and restart Mist again. This way you free up ram so you can make crypto memes in photoshop.

Comment: Yep, but he was asking how to stop and delete it... :-)